# Importing collada meshes in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I created a robot mesh in Blender, and now I want to import it in Gazebo. The problem is that, when I insert the model in Gazebo, the shape is good, but it is completely black, altought it had different colours in Blender. To color the object in Blender, I added some new materials.
The result of exporting to collada was just *robot.dae* file. Maybe there should be some other files representing materials? The part of the SDF that imports mesh looks like this:

```
<geometry>
   <mesh><uri>file://robot.dae</uri></mesh>
</geometry>
```

...for both visual and collision tag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3091/importing-collada-meshes-in-gazebo/) by [bot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/345/bot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Take a look in `~/.gazebo/ogre.log`. There are probably errors that say a material cannot be found.

Gazebo will search for materials in all paths listed in GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH. It's important to note that for each path listed in `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`, gazebo will search in the `media/materials/textures` subdirectory.

For example, if `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/local/share/gazebo-1.8`. The material texture files should be in `/usr/local/share/gazebo-1.8/media/materials/textures`.

You should probably just make a model, which has a self-contained directory struture for all meshes, materials, and SDF files. See [here](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__models__database.html), and these [examples](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0